# Go, go get, go install, local packages, and version control

Tags: git, package, go

I am having trouble understanding the workflow for creating a go project that has local packages.

Say I create a new project, using git for version control, which has a main.go file and a tools.go file which will be in package utils. So I have a directory structure such as this:

```
/myproject/
   main.go
   utils/
     tools.go
```

main.go looks like this:

```
package main
import "./utils"
func main() {
    utils.DoSomthing()
}
```

and tools.go looks like this:

```
package utils;
func DoSomething() {
}
```

Everything works just fine locally, using *go build* and *go run*. But this is being hosted on github, and I'd like to be able to have others use the *go get* command to install it. So the local package import must be changed to use the format "github.com/user/project/utils", which works, except now I have two copies of the source code, and the real problem is that the copy with the git history has an import that makes use of the downloaded copy. So if I'm working on the copy with the git history, any changes made to tools.go will go unnoticed, because it will be using the downloaded copy.

So I'm wondering if someone can explain the right way of using *go get*, version control, and package imports within the same project.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

I've just written a short step-by-step guide on how I am using the new [go tool](http://golang.org/cmd/go/) and [github.com](http://github.com/). You might find it useful:

**1. Setup your GOPATH**

You can set the environment variable `GOPATH` to any directory you like. If you have larger projects, it's probably a good idea to create a different GOPATH for each of them. I would recommend this approach especially for the deployment, so that updating a library for project A doesn't break project B which might require an earlier version of the very same library.

Also note that you can set your GOPATH to a list of directories, delimited by colons. So you might have a GOPATH containing all commonly used packages, and separate GOPATHS for each project with additonal packages or different versions of existing packages.

But unless your are working on a lot of different Go projects simultaneously, its probably enough to have just a single GOPATH locally. So, let's create one:

```
mkdir $HOME/gopath
```

Then you need to set two environment variables to tell the [go tool](http://golang.org/cmd/go/) where it can find existing Go packages and where it should install new ones. It's probably best to add the following two lines to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` (and do not forget to reload your .bashrc afterwards).

```
export GOPATH="$HOME/gopath"
export PATH="$GOPATH/bin:$PATH"
```

**2. Create a new project**

If you want to create a new Go project which should be hosted at [github.com](https://github.com/) later, you should create this project under `$GOPATH/src/github.com/myname/myproject`. It's important that the path matches the URL of the github.com repo, because the go tool will follow the same convention. So, let's create the project root and initialize a new git repository there:

```
mkdir -p $GOPATH/src/github.com/myname/myproject
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/myname/myproject
git init
```

Because I do not like to type such long paths, I normally create symbolic links for the projects I am currently working on in my home folder:

```
ln -s $GOPATH/src/github.com/myname/myproject ~/myproject
```

**3. Write your application**

Start coding and don't forget to `git add` and `git commit` your files. Also, do not use relative imports like `import "./utils"` for sub-packages. They are currently undocumented and shouldn't be used at all, because they won't work with the go tool. Use imports like `github.com/myname/myproject/utils` instead.

**4. Publish your project**

Create a [new repository at github.com](https://github.com/repositories/new), upload your SSH public key if you haven't done that before and push your changes to the remote repository:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:myname/myproject.git
git push origin master
```

**5. Continue working on your project**

If you have set the GOPATH in your .bashrc and if you have created a symlink to your project in your home folder, you can just type `cd myproject/` and edit some files there. Afterwards, you can commit the changes using `git commit -a` and send them to [github.com](https://github.com/) by doing a `git push`.

Comment: I have been getting the hang of this lately myself. What I started doing was having a single GOPATH, and symlinking my projects into them. That way i can easily build, but keep the actual projects in their own repos. It feels like a pretty clean approach so far.

Comment: Github path tend to be long and I'm lazy, so I added an alias to my bashrc: `alias g="cd /home/me/goroot/src/github.com/me/"`. Now I can shortcut to my projects with simple g command.

Comment: How do you keep track of the external dependencies that your packages is using?

Comment: Can this be applied if I'm using a CI server ? I'm assuming on each push the CI would try to `go get` the local package from the `master` branch which may not be the same version to test. Any pointers on using a CI with go ? @tux21b

Comment: @tux21b can I ask u another question, how to host the project onto different repo? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51413252/how-to-oraganize-go-project-packages-if-it-will-hosted-on-different-reposgithub

Answer (score 11):

You probably don't want two copies of the source.  Following [How to Write Go Code](http://golang.org/doc/code.html), you should have a path where you do your Go development, lets say "godev", and under that, a "src" directory, and under that, your "github.com/user/project" and "github.com/user/project/utils".  (I agree, it seems a little rigid, but the advantage explained to us is freedom from make files.)  Ditch the myproject, this is where you will do your work.

You will have GOPATH set to godev at least, but you will probably want your GOPATH to start with a path for external packages that are not yours.  For example the GOPATH I use is `<my place on the file system>/goext:<my place on the file system>/godev`.

You are right that your import in main.go should now read "github.com/user/project/utils.

Don't worry about go get or any of the go commands overwriting your files or messing up version control.  Through GOPATH, they see where you are working and they know how version control works.

Comment: I had a related issue, and was following your guidelines here, but am now getting an "import loop" error. I have my source in <my location>\godev\src\github.com\user\project and the project imports "github.com/user/project".

Comment: Your project shouldn't try to import itself.  Just going by the example code above still, your main program should be importing "github.com/user/project/utils".

Answer (score 9):

If you want to keep your code in local version repository, just put your code in GOPATH.

GOPATH accepts multiple paths.
eg. on linux

```
GOPATH=$HOME/go:$HOME/prj/foo
```

So, you could go get 3rd party packages installed in $HOME/go/src/...
And, you could keep your code controlled in $HOME/prj/foo/src.

ref: `go help gopath`

Comment: This! Or Sonia's answer.

Answer (score -2):

lot of people say should use absolutlly path to construct project struct and import :

```
import "github.com/user/utils"
```

but this may limit your project within a single repo (github).  I would like to use 
relative path instead :

```
  import "./utils"
```

I havn't find a way to do that, I  raise a question here:
[how to oraganize GO project packages if it will hosted on different repos(github & sourceForge)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51413252/how-to-oraganize-go-project-packages-if-it-will-hosted-on-different-reposgithub)

Answer (score -4):

After looking for this answer in different posts and Go documentation, with Go 1.11 there has been released a new approach to handle packages and is using Go Modules.

Read the whole post series about Go Modules [here](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules).

Go Modules also takes care of version control as well